# Site appears in Google in the US with a site: operator, but won't show up in Google India

Tags: google, domains, search-engine-indexing, search-results

When I am trying to see my page over google using search operator **site:**
From United States the url got visible
[image]
but when I search the same url using the same search operator with an Indian IP the url does not show up. Can anyone explain why is this happpening?

[image]